# Windows authentication skip for one folder and allow local domain's user

Tags: authentication

I have intranet application with windows authentication on it. Annonymous users are not allowed. Now i am trying to add one subfolder which should be allowed to local domain users too. I enabled "annonymous access" iis on that subfolder and that worked. but i am using AJAX(timer control) on one of page of that subfolder and when timer_ticks it gives "sys is undefined error". any idea to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You will have to probably disable integrated authentication for that subfolder, as IIS sees that setting and tries it first, which it does by sending an auth request, basically a fail message to the browser.. your ajax script probably isn't testing for that fail, so doesn't know to send the data again.